# Why is the transformer Jelly Bean update being staggered geographically?

Tags: updates, asus-eee-pad-transformer, 4.1-jelly-bean

The Transformer TF300's jelly bean update is now available OTA in North America but not in Australia for up to two weeks.

What would be the reason that they would not make it available all at once? Is there some technical reason it can't be done? Like if I was in the US but I bought the tablet in Australia, would it let me update?

So is there any way for me to bypass this restriction and somehow hook into the North American update site (via a proxy or something) in order to get it now?

Answer (score 2):

Each region has its own network-dependent versions (with additional apps / bloatware).

You can use the firmwares from other regions, which you can find in [SamFirmware](http://www.samfirmware.com/), but you need to have a rooted phone.

Comment: but this tablet is wi-fi only. wouldn't wifi be the same everywhere in the world and not be reliant on any phone networks?

Comment: @Diskdrive You're right; your point on the wi-fi makes sense. I suppose you can just root it with with another firmware. I don't think there'd be any difference anyway. But it could probably have different GPS settings [although it could be fixed with an app] or other region-specific settings.